# Get file in JAR using Servlet 3.0 Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlet-3.0

Servlet 3.0 has a great feature: I can access static resources in JARs using the META-INF/resources folder. So if I have a javascript inside my JAR I can access using
http://myurl.com/myapp/myjavascript.js. That's great. 
But... How to to get that file from the jar to manipulate it or do something with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) the usual way to get an `InputStream` of it:

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/javascript.js");
```

As to your intent to manipulate it, forget it. This resoure is not writable. Basically, you'd need to extract the whole JAR, manipulate the entry, repack the JAR and supply a custom classloader to reload it and tell the container to use it. Even if you succeed in this, all changes would get lost once you redeploy the WAR or in certain configurations even if you just restart the server, for the very simple reason that those changes are not contained in the original WAR.

You're going in the wrong path as to solving the concrete functional requirement. I recommend to take a step back and ask a new question about how to solve the particular concrete functional requirement for which you incorrectly thought that *this* would be the right solution.

Comment: Thank you!, your answer is good. My problem is the following: I use pack:tag to compress some resources(javascript, css) but some resources I have packed in a JAR and I wanted to packtag to get that resources with no success.

Comment: So I wanted to hack a little the source code of packtag and I wanted to know what is the right way to access the resources inside my jar